# Convert a list to another list containing strings

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I am learning Python data structures
Trying to convert

```
    ['io.o compat.o token.o']
```

to

```
    ['io.o', 'compat.o', 'token.o']
```

I have tried split based on spaces but that works only for strings and not lists.

```
    >>> list1=['io.o compat.o token.o']
    >>> list2=list1.split()
    Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
    AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'split'
```

I also looked at other functions supported on lists like copy but could not figure out how to do the above

Comment: You should split the string at index 0 in the list. Try `list2 = list1[0].split()`.

Comment: Why is the string wrapped in a list? There's only the one string.

Comment: It's not clear what you want exactly? Does the original list always only have one item? In that case you can simply extract it `list1[0].split()`. Otherwise, what do you want to happen to a list with multiple strings?

Comment: You have to apply split the *str*, not to the *list*.  `list[0].split`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
list1 = ['io.o compat.o token.o']
list2 = list1[0].split()
```

[resources for list](https://www.pythonforbeginners.com/dictionary/python-split)

Answer (score 1):

That is because it's already a list - you can't split a list.

```
temp = ['io.o compat.o token.o']
temp_list = []
for item in temp:
    temp_list.extend(item.split())
print(temp_list)
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like that should work:

```
p = ['io.o compat.po token.o']  
p = p[0].split(' ')
```

Comment: `split()` returns a list, not an iterator, there's no reason to wrap it in `list()`.

Comment: There is also no need for the `' '` argument as it is the default

Answer (score 0):

If more than 1 string in the input list you could do:

```
temp = ['io.o compat.o token.o']
result = [item.split() for item in temp]
print(result)
```

**OUTPUT:-**

```
[['io.o', 'compat.o', 'token.o']]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
dd = ['io.o compat.o token.o']
result = [i.split(" ") for i in dd][0]
# result =['io.o', 'compat.o', 'token.o']
```